# How do I repair a Disk (is not booting)

Tags: boot, system, boot-repair, restore

My hard drive will not boot. The screen comes up blank. It was working fine yesterday. No changes made. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on 64-bit. 
On the same computer, I am using an USB emergency installation to do this work. It booted just fine, all computer hardware also tested OK; hence, the problem is the Ubuntu installation. 
This computer is ubuntu dedicated (no dual boot.)

Answer (score 2):

Try use [`Boot-Repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for repair.

To add Boot-Repair to the repository use:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

To update your repository:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

To install boot-repair:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Once Installation completes, run boot-repair on terminal by typing the following command or select it by `System` → `Administration` → `Boot Repair`.

```
$ boot-repair
```

Comment: @user256807 if it worked for you please flag the answer as accepted.